# php constructor in a field assign the last value

Tags: php

Php version is 7.1.
I want to initialize class fields with values, but it fails.

Why does php in a class constructor in a field assign the last value?

```
class Order
{
    private $yourname;
    private $yourphone;

    public function __construct(string $p_yourname, string $p_yourphone) 
     { 
        $this->$yourphone =$p_yourphone;
        $this->$yourname=$p_yourname;

    echo  $p_yourname;
    echo  $p_yourphone;
    echo  $this->$yourphone;
    echo  $this->$yourname;
     }
}
```

call conctructor

```
$order = new Order( '﻿Andry', '+79777475675');
```

Result in echo is: ﻿Andry+79777475675AndryAndry

Comment: `$this->$yourphone` should be `$this->yourphone` same for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear. The parameter name and the field name in the constructor must be the same.
The syntax for assignment in the constructor should be like this $this->yourphone =$yourphone;

That's right so

```
public function __construct(string $yourphone, string $yourname) 
     { 
        $this->yourphone =$yourphone;
        $this->yourname=$yourname;
        echo  $yourphone;
        echo  $yourname;
        echo  $this->$yourphone;
        echo  $this->$yourname;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Correction:

```
class Order
{
    private $yourname;
    private $yourphone;

    public function __construct(string $p_yourname, string $p_yourphone) 
     { 
        $this->yourphone =$p_yourphone;
        $this->yourname=$p_yourname;

    echo  $p_yourname;
    echo  $p_yourphone;
    echo  $this->yourphone;
    echo  $this->yourname;
     }
}
```